# Can't access localStorage in my own Hook with Next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to make a hook in which the User credentials are stored (authToken etc.). I want to save the user to the localStorage so I made a custom hook which does that. Unfortunately, my code doesn't compile because `window is not defined`. Im using the next framework so I guess it's because node doesn't have the `window` object. How can I make it compile? I only want to use the hook on client side, so the window object should always be available...

My Hook:

```
    interface User {
    username: string;
    userId: string;
    authToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    language: Language;
}

export default function useUser(): [User | null, (user: User | null) => void] {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(getLocalStorage('user'));

    if (window?.localStorage) {
        window.addEventListener('storage', () =>
            setUser(getLocalStorage('user'))
        );
    }

    return [user, user => setLocalStorage('user', user)];
}

function getLocalStorage<T>(key: string): T | null {
    if (window?.localStorage) {
        const storage = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        return storage && JSON.parse(storage);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function setLocalStorage(key: string, value?: any): void {
    if (value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } else {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u need to understand how SSR works, NextJS will build React app into static file, which mean during the build time, the code run within server-side, it's server machine, not user's browser, that's why **`window`** object is not define.

Instead, u consider solution as below

- load data from `localStorage` within
  `componentDidMount` or `useEffect`.
- If you are using NextJS, you can also [customize App (docs)](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) and
  combine with React Context on component mount to share state in whole application.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `localStorage` without putting `window` before, using React

For example, `window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));` becomes `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));`

Comment: Hello, I tried it with only the localStorage, doesnt work unfortunately. Im guessing because I use next.js, It thinks I want to run the code on node, which I dont, I only want to run it on the client (the browser)

Comment: maybe try adding this check ? ```if (typeof window !== "undefined") { // code here }```

Comment: You know what I could try? i could make it so the hook takes an object as parameter which extends the interface "Storage" with the method getItem, setItem etc. I would then pass the localStorage on clientside